# gcloud has the problem of parsing the path of my google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, gcloud, google-colaboratory, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I try to run Google's Image example of AI Explanations.
Link: https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/ml-on-gcp/blob/master/tutorials/explanations/ai-explanations-image.ipynb

And, I use these code mount my google drive

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Then, I export the model to my Google Drive with

```
export_path = keras_estimator.export_saved_model(
  '/content/gdrive/My Drive/xai_flower/',
  serving_input_receiver_fn
).decode('utf-8')
```

But when I want use

```
!gcloud beta ai-platform versions create $VERSION \
--model $MODEL \
--origin $export_path \
--runtime-version 1.14 \
--framework TENSORFLOW \
--python-version 3.5 \
--machine-type n1-standard-4 \
--explanation-method integrated-gradients \
--num-integral-steps 25
```

It will output

```
/bin/bash: /content/gdrive/My: No such file or directory
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) unrecognized arguments: Drive/xai_flower/1576834069
```

Obviously, gcloud has the problem of parsing the path with space.

I have tried to rename "My Drive" with other words, but it seems to be unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Please try escaping the space in the path using a backslash (`\`), i.e.

```
export_path = keras_estimator.export_saved_model(
  '/content/gdrive/My\ Drive/xai_flower/',
  serving_input_receiver_fn
).decode('utf-8')
```